# UPDATE specific column in SQL Server database from asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

How to update a table from the database, with the click of a button

```
protected void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    string insCmd = "UPDATE Orders SET finish = 1  WHERE finish IS NULL";

    SqlCommand addOrder = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);
    addOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("finish", 1);

    con.Close();
}
```

Please help

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: dont work,  not update database :(

Comment: Where do you execute the command?

Comment: in page.asp.cs   on web

Comment: What @Jens is pointing out is that you don't actually execute the `SqlCommand` that you've built up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must run Sql statement with below code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        string insCmd = "UPDATE Orders SET finish = 1  WHERE finish IS NULL";

       SqlCommand addOrder = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);
       addOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("finish", 1);
       addOrder.ExecuteNonQuery();

       con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You Need too excecute the command:

```
  SqlCommand addOrder = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);
  addOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@finish", 1);
  addOrder.ExecuteNonQuery();
```